# IDP initiated SSO from Google SAML with Keycloak as identity broker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak, saml, google-sso

We have Google SAML SSO login (IDP) in our Spring boot application (SP) with Keycloak as IDP broker. The SP initated login `(SpringApp -> keycloak -> GoogleSSO -> keycloak -> Spring)` works fine. However, if I login to my google account and click my saml application tile from the google app menu, the SSO fails at ACS endpoint with the below error.

[image: Keycloak webpage error image]

Below error is logged inside keycloak server logs.

> ERROR [org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService] (default
> task-424) invalidRequestMessage
>
> WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-424)
> type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=****-realm,
> clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=x.x.x.x,
> error=invalidRequestMessage

**Keycloak Identity Provider Configuration**

- Created new SAML v2.0 Identity provider from Identity providers menu.
- Redirect URI : *https://{keycloak-root}/auth/realms/{realm-name}/broker/{alias}/endpoint*
- First Login Flow: *first broker login*
- Service Provider Entity ID: *https://{keycloak-root}/auth/realms/{realm-name}*
- Single Sign-On Service URL: *{google idp sso url}*

**Keycloak Client Configuration:**

- Created a new keycloak client for sso.
- Client Protocol: *SAML*
- Signature Algorithm: *RSA_SHA_256*
- Name ID Format: *Username*
- Valid Redirect URIs: *{spring-boot-app-url} after successful authentication from google and keycloak*
- IDP Initiated SSO URL Name: *{app-name-string}*
- IDP Initiated SSO Relay State: *{spring-boot-app-url}*
- Assertion Consumer Service POST Binding URL: *{spring-boot-app-url}*

**Google SAML App Configuration:**

- Entity ID: *https://{keycloak-root}/auth/realms/{realm-name}*
- ACS URL:  *https://{keycloak-root}/auth/realms/{realm-name}/broker/{alias}/endpoint*

Please suggest if any configuration changes has to be made to make idp initiated login work.

**UPDATE:**
We compared the saml request of both SP and IDP login. In IDP login, on successful redirection from google to keycloak ACS url, we found the `RelayState` parameter is empty. But in SP login, same `RelayState` parameter has a string value present, which changes on every login.

We could set a default value for `RelayState` using the `Start URL` field inside Google SAML app. But the problem is keycloak generates this value dynamically that changes on every login request.

Comment: So how SAML request looks like? I bet you have wrong entity ID.

Comment: During IDP initiated login, the RelayState parameter is empty. But if I login through SP, keycloak send some random string in RelayState parameter. I suspect this could be the reason for IDP initiated login failure. EntityID is correct